# input object into function without new class or object

Tags: javascript

I trying to input a object into a function without creating a new class or object and then log the output.
function:

```
function log_input(object) {
  console.log(object.property)
}
```

could i do something like this:

```
log_input(this.property = "info")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in different ways, but not by keyword argument way. You can pass as an object like `log_input({ })` syntax and another easy way like below-

```js
this.property = "info"

function log_input(object) {
  console.log(object.property)
}

log_input(this)
```

```js
function log_input(object) {
  console.log(object.property)
}

log_input({property:'info'})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object literal:

```
log_input({ property: "info" })
```